# удалить последние два элемента из массива js

Tags: javascript

столкнулся со следующей задачей: Есть Массив из парных чисел (это координаты кликов мыши)  let array =[35,154,62,169,98,30,150,250]
как сделать, чтоб при нажатии кнопки удалялись по парно элементы с конца массива?
метод array.pop() удаляет только последний элемент и один раз.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь или подсказку в каком направлении копать дальше!

```html
<button id="delete" class="button">Remove</button>
<script>
let array =[35,154,62,169,98,30,150,250];
_id("delete").addEventListener("click", function () {
  array.pop();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 

```
array.pop();
array.pop();
```

2. 

```
array.length = array.length - 2;
```

3. 

```
array.splice(array.length - 2, 2);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, второй вариант очень помог!